# comma separated wmic commands

Tags: batch-file, wmic

i made this script that uses wmic to get info from remote computer

```
set /p "user=write UserName="
set /p "password=write Password="


for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ip.txt) do ( 

    wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% computersystem get Name /format:table
    wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% computersystem get Model /format:table
    wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% computersystem get totalphysicalmemory /format:table
    wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% cpu get Name /format:table
    wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% path Win32_VideoController get Name /format:table
    wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% os get Caption /format:table
    wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% csproduct get identifyingnumber /format:table
    wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% desktopmonitor get screenheight /format:table
    wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% desktopmonitor get screenwidth /format:table

  )>>a.csv
```

but the output is a bit weird it seperates with "enter" any idea how to comma separate?

Comment: For the same class you can get multiple values, like: `wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% computersystem get Name,Model /format:table` (the columns are sorted alphabetically by property)

Comment: yeah but when i put it in an csv file i need it to comma separated so i can importi it to another program to organize

Comment: In pure batch scripting this is not trivial, as `wmic` produces Unicode output which leads to some trouble; however, you could execute _every_ `wmic` command line within `for /F` loops so the loops parse the output: `for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic OS GET Caption /VALUE') do for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("%%B") do echo(%%Z` (there are two loops: the outer one splits off the value of interest, the inner one removes potential orphaned trailing carriage-return characters which are left by the outer one during Unicode/ANSI conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code snippet:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /P "user=write UserName="
set /P "password=write Password="
> "a.csv" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("ip.txt") do (
        set "lineString="
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% computersystem             get Name                /value') do for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("%%B") do set "lineString=!lineString!,%%Z"
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% computersystem             get Model               /value') do for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("%%B") do set "lineString=!lineString!,%%Z"
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% computersystem             get totalphysicalmemory /value') do for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("%%B") do set "lineString=!lineString!,%%Z"
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% cpu                        get Name                /value') do for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("%%B") do set "lineString=!lineString!,%%Z"
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% path Win32_VideoController get Name                /value') do for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("%%B") do set "lineString=!lineString!,%%Z"
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% os                         get Caption             /value') do for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("%%B") do set "lineString=!lineString!,%%Z"
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% csproduct                  get identifyingnumber   /value') do for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("%%B") do set "lineString=!lineString!,%%Z"
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% desktopmonitor             get screenheight        /value') do for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("%%B") do set "lineString=!lineString!,%%Z"
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('wmic /node:%%a /user:%user% /password:%password% desktopmonitor             get screenwidth         /value') do for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("%%B") do set "lineString=!lineString!,%%Z"
        if defined lineString echo(!lineString:~1!
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

The `wmic` output is stored into a `,`-separated string in the variable `lineString`. For capturing the output of a command a `for /F` loop is perfect. However, the `wmic` command produces Unicode output, so two nested `for /F` loops are needed to do a proper Unicode/ANSI conversion; a single loop would leave orphaned trailing carriage-return characters in the strings.

The output format of `wmic` has been changed from `/format:table` to `/value` to get an output like this: `Caption=Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise`, so the `for /F` loop can take the `=` as a delimiter and get the desired value.

Besides all this, I also changed the following:

In your code, you redirected the output of every single loop iteration separately. To avoid this, `()` have been put around the (outer-most) `for /F` loop, so the whole data is redirected once into `a.csv`. Hence the redirection operator has been changed from append-type `>>` to (over-)write-type `>`.

[Delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) has been enabled which is required when modifying and reading a variable (`lineString`) within `for` loops or blocks of code in between `()`.

Comment: I just found out that I missed an `=` in the `demils=` options of the `for /F` loops; and I inserted `@echo off` at the beginning to avoid any command echos to be output to file `a.txt`; see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34909662/2)...

Comment: amazing, thanks !, i think i understand, but why did `/format:table` change to `/value` ?

Comment: Say we have `wmic OS get Caption /format:table`, the output would be a line `Caption`, followed by `Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise`, so to get the value, the surrounding `for /F` loop needs to iterate twice, or I'd need to hard-code a certain line (number) to be taken; with `/value` there is only a single line; all this is true only in case a single value is requested by `wmic`; however, if you prefer to use `/format:table`, you can do that, provided you adapt the `for /F` options accordingly: `"skip=1 delims="` instead of `"tokens=1,* delims=="`

Comment: You're welcome! ...just to complete the above comment: when using `/format:table` and the adapted `for /F` options, you also need to read variable `%%A` rather than `%%B` (there is no `tokens` option defined, so it defaults to `1`, hence there is only `%%A` and no `%%B`)...